# org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: .fop (Access is denied) in Azure

Tags: java, apache-fop

I have recently added a fop pdf generator to an existing application. everything works fine locally but when I deploy to live on Azure I get the following errors:

```
org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: .fop (Access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .fop (Access is denied)
```

I'm puzzled as to why I'm getting a file access error when it would seem the exception is occurring when the fopfactory writes to a ByteOutputstream

The function where the catch occurs is

```
        public static void GeneratePDF(string foFile, HttpContext context) {
        StringBuilder sbDebug = new StringBuilder();

        sbDebug.AppendLine("Start");
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 1");
            com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl s = new com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl();
            sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 2");
            FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new java.io.File(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Test.xconf")));
            sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 3 - file ").AppendLine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Test.xconf"));
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", os);

            sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 4");
            javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory factory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
            javax.xml.transform.Source src = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(foFile));
            javax.xml.transform.Result res = new javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 5");
            transformer.transform(src, res);

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(os.toByteArray());
            //context.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(os.ToString()));
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception(sbDebug.AppendLine(ex.ToString()).ToString());
        }

        finally {
            os.close();
        }
    }
```

You can see I've added some debug lines as I had to resort to old fashioned debugging to see what was happening.
The output from this is:

```
Catch Error: System.Exception: Start
Got to 1
Got to 2
Got to 3 - file 
D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Test.xconf
org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: .fop (Access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .fop (Access is denied)
```

So I can see the exception is occurring at this line:

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", os);
```

I'm expecting everything to be happening in memory apart from the read of the xconf file which is where it should be.

**Update 21/02/2017** I've now verified that the xconf file exists in the correct place using

```
string curFile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Test.xconf");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(curFile)) //Used System.IO prefix as without it compiler complains of ambiguity with java.io
            {
                sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 3a - file found");
            }
            else
            {
                sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 3a - file NOT found");
            }
```

And also that it can be read using

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(curFile));
            sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 3b");

            String sJIObrOut = br.readLine();
            sbDebug.AppendLine("Got to 3c");
            while ((sJIObrOut = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sbDebug.Append("3d: ").AppendLine(sJIObrOut);
            }
```

This suggest that fopfactory is trying to access a different file but I can't figure out what.

Any help gratefully received.

**UPDATE 2 22/3/17**
I had no success with Azure Cloud services so decided to build a local web app to just convert the xslfo doc to a pdf and run it as a web service. This works perfectly locally so published the service on a server we use for other clients. 
This doesn't work and I get exactly the same error as my original post. That means it's not an Azure problem - does any one have any other ideas?

Comment: On my Linux System, .fop is used to store cache files like font-cache. It is located under `/home/USER/.fop` where USER is the user tomcat runs with. So I presume FOP wants to create this file somewhere under `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local` in Windows, what may be not allowed with Azure. I am a Linux guy, so I do not know for sure, but maybe it helps nonetheless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very many thanks to @mondjunge for pointing me in the right direction. I now have a solution which works outside of Azure for now - In due course I'm hoping this will be something I can apply to Azure directly, and I will add to this post accordingly

It seems as if the cache writing is what is causing the problem (permissions).

The workaround/fix I have implemented is to add the following line into the xconf file (I put it just before the /fop closing tag but don't think it matters as long as it's a direct child node of fop)

```
<use-cache>false</use-cache>
```

Hope this saves someone else days of hassle and stress

**Update 7/4/17**

Out of interest I tried adding this line to the pure azure hosted version and it no longer gave me the permissions error instead it gave me an error about GDI which is probably along the lines of what @PeterPan suggested originally. Since I have a working version of the fop application hosted elsewhere I'm going to leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

ApacheFOP will created localy .Fop(folder) in the frist run and inside this folder will be create cache-fonts.cache file(this cache file is for performance if you would like to define some other font-arial, which are not supportet from Apache FOP and a lot of other things).
if you go in your windows user, you will find this .fop folder 
Anyway, i think that azure don't allow apache fop to create this .fop Folder on the server to create inside this .fop the fop-cache.cache file

I spent some time to get the solution!
here is solution for my Problem( it is working on windows Server)
Steps:
1- you define the Path where the fop-fonts.cache
2- you have to adapt the path with of the cache file
3- set cache path, where fop-fonts.cache will be created

Code:

```
    // create just Fop folder and inside this a Cache FOP Folder on your 
    // project
    // Tipp: you could read it from config
    // fop-fonts.cache have to be created automaticly, if it is running good
    string fopcacheFilePath = "~/Fop/Cache Fop/fop-fonts.cache"; 

    fopcacheFilePath = fopcacheFilePath.Replace("\\","/");
    fopcacheFilePath = "file:///" + fopcacheFilePath;
    fopcacheFilePath = fopcacheFilePath.Replace(" ", "%20");
    //in your case you have to set fopcacheFilePath
    fopFactory.getFontManager().setCacheFile(new URI(fopcacheFilePath))
```

if this code have been running without problem, then you have to find the fop-fonts.cache in your projectfolder

Comment: Thanks @Moe - I'm going to leave this for now as I have the fonts I need and a working solution. I may try your suggestion if it becomes necessary to have other fonts

Comment: It's also possible to set it on the fop-config.xml file <cache-file>file:///tmp/fop-fonts.cache</cache-file>

Answer (score 0):

I researched for Apache FOP, I discovered that the PDF generating feature is based on Java [AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/java2d.html#gcgtf) which using Default DirectDraw/GDI Pipeline on Windows OS. However, according to the kudu wiki page [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), you can get the restrictions information for GDI via search the keyword `GDI`. So normally the workaround way is using a library without GDI, but seems that almost all Java libraries for imaging were depended on AWT.

Besides using Azure Cloud Services or VM, you could not generate PDF on Azure App Services which include WebApps.

Comment: the fop pdfgenrator I am using now (crispin.fop) is a replacement for fonet which is a very old .NET port of apache FOP and being replaced due to lack of support for many xsl:fo features. This solution worked fine on Azure to produce PDFs - do you have any ideas why that would work and this doesn't?

Comment: How about running this on App Service on Linux? I know it's in preview, but maybe it is a viable approach for the future?

Comment: Looking at the original fault I have posted, I'm not convinced that we've even reached the stage when GDI would be involved. I'm far from an expert on this but I would expect the GDI stuff doesn't happen until the transformer is initiated/invoked which happens after the exception is thrown - do you concur?

Comment: Please see my update 22/3/17 - Azure is not the problem - any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved giving access to the users of IIS to modify the path: (Windows Server)

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
```

The home path in my local machine is `User\My User`, but in the server the path is that in the system32 folder.

```
string home = java.lang.System.getProperty("user.home"); // return the home path
```

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It worked!

FYI
for typical Java Spring Tomcat app, the config file should be located under WEB-INF

or

Find it from source where you are setting the input stream for use with the configuration object

--sample code for your reference

```
Resource config = m_appContext.getResource ("/WEB-INF/user_config.xml");
DefaultConfigurationBuilder builder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder (true);
m_config = builder.build (config.getInputStream ());
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
if (null != m_config)
     fopFactory.setUserConfig (m_config);
```

Comment: Re: to <use-cache>false</use-cache>